# Can`t figure how this function works

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, slider

I have down here some code from a tutorial for a fullscreen image slider,i understand all the code beside one part which resets the slider in a function! It s confuse me how

```
current===sliderImages.length -1
```

and then

```
current = -1;
```

HERE IS THE CODE

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
    current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
    current--;
}
// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
});

// Show next
function slideRight() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
    current++;
}

                        THIS FUNCTION I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW IT WORKS
// Right arrow click    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
  !!!!  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {  
        current = -1;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
    slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement checks if the `current` is last element. If the code still runs after this condition then current will become equal to `length` of `sliderImages` and it will be `undefined` because **index of last element of array is always equal to length of array minus 1**

```
if (current === sliderImages.length - 1)
```

If you have reached the last image then change `current` to `-1`. Now you may ask why its set to `-1`. The array indexes starts from `0`. This is because in `slideRight()` `1` will be added to `current` so it will become `0` i.e the first element of array

```
sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: @DConstantin **but that** Ask if still something is unclear

Comment: for me the logic will be  if (current === sliderImages.length ) { current =-1}

Answer (score 0):

In above code

```
var current = 0;
if slider image length 0 > then it's sliding arrow works. !
```